# is Association a aprt of inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi guys hope i can get some help clearing this question. I have 2 models , Generator and Result. A generator belongs_to result and result belongs to generator.

In my Result model,there will be 1 function where i need to know the attribute value of generator. How can i get the value ?

for example : generator_id =1 has 'aggtc'( generator.primer ='aggtc')
in my results model , i need  to retrieve generator.primer . How should i do it ?

Does the association help ? ( i have a user model to be consider later on ) a user has many results and generators

Answer (score 1):

i think you have a mistake in your logic, you shouldnt have 2 models that belong to each other, if thats the case is probably better to use has_one, in your logic who has the foreing_key in that generator-result relation?

normal relations should be like this generator has_many results, result belongs_to generator

here is some documentation on relations:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html